# git-archive does not work with special file names on Windows even for bare repositories. Is it a bug of the implementation?

Tags: git

Suppose I have created a tiny Git repository at a Linux machine:

```sh
git init bad-filenames
cd bad-filenames
touch con prn.ext ':' '\'
git add .
git commit -m 'bad filenames'
git push <REMOTE_GIT_REPO_URL> master
```

Now on a Windows machine I clone the repo making it bare since none of the above files can be checked out at Windows machines because their filenames are unsupported for the known reasons (yes, I'm aware of the UNC path format too, but it's not relevant to the issue):

```
git clone --bare <REMOTE_GIT_REPO_URL>
cd bad-filenames
```

It surprises me, but creating an archive using `git-archive` results in a fatal error regardless the given format:

```
git archive origin/master
git archive --format=tar origin/master
git archive --format=tar.gz origin/master
git archive --format=tgz origin/master
git archive --format=zip origin/master
```

```
error: invalid path 'con'
```

If I remove bad filenames one after another from the commit, then it still results in errors:

```
error: invalid path ':'

error: invalid path '\'

error: invalid path 'prn.ext'
```

The above `git-archive` works perfectly at the Linux machine. The Git service I'm using for the test also can produce a valid archive that can be open on the Windows machine at least by using tools like Far Manager (it goes into stack overflow when trying to calculate it's size thinking it's a path `/`, but succeeds with extracting all of the files renaming `\` to `_` and `:` to `…` respectively) and 7-Zip (the GUI seems to work fine at the first glance, but `7z x <ARCHIVE_FILE_PATH>` fuses `\` and `:` into a single file named `_`).

I'm wondering, is it a bug in the Windows implementation of Git? The reason of why I tend to think so is that all of those formats can be generated programmatically (thus it's possible to read blobs directly from the repository and write them to the target archive stream), but it looks like the target file system is the blocker regardless if I use the `--output` option or shell redirection with `>` even writing to `nul`. Or is it implemented like that intentionally?

Comment: Windows has some restricted filenames. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file Here, Git for Windows is just reflecting a limitation in the underlying system. A similar problem occurs if on unix you create files or branches that only differ by case (eg: X.h and x.h). The Windows filesystem can't represent them as it has case insensitive filesystems.

Comment: @patthoyts Yes, but generating an archive out of the commit does not need files being archived to be intermediately stored when generating the archive. In short, it would assume that generating an archive out of a commit or tree would never consider the underlying file system specifics.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* deliberate: see [the `is_valid_path` call in `read-cache.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5/read-cache.c#L1030-L1031) and note that this is a macro, with one expansion for Windows and another for non-Windows:

[`compat/mingw.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/compat/mingw.h):

```
int is_valid_win32_path(const char *path, int allow_literal_nul);
#define is_valid_path(path) is_valid_win32_path(path, 0)
```

[`git-compat-util.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-compat-util.h):

```
#ifndef is_valid_path
#define is_valid_path(path) 1
#endif
```

> I'm wondering, is it a bug in the Windows implementation of Git?

[One man's meat is another man's poison](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/one-man-s-meat-is-another-man-s-poison).  Bug or feature: you decide.

Comment: It's not nice when an operation that does not require _checking out_ blobs at the target filesystem with _their original names_ makes the test. I also cannot see why it is _deliberate_ to check names of blobs that are not going to be checked out and most likely not to be stored on the target file system as intermediate files (with their original names). Cannot check it at the moment, but it sounds like the `--output` option makes the test too ( https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/compat/mingw.c#L2633 may go that far)... It really looks like a bug or a bad design item to me.